# How to show $P_3(R)=W\oplus W_1$ and $P_3(R)=W\oplus W_2$ based on the following assumption?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, axioms

Let $W=$Span$\{1, x\}$, $W_1=$Span$\{x^2, x^3\}$ and $W_2=$Span$\{1+x+x^2+x^3, 1+x+x^2-x^3\}$, how to show $P_3(R)=W\oplus W_1$ and $P_3(R)=W\oplus W_2$?

$P_3(R)=W+ W_1$ because Span$\{1, x\}$+Span$\{x^2, x^3\}$=$a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$, which represents any polynomial.

For $W\cap W_1=\{0\}$, I don't know how to show it.

$P_3(R)=W+ W_2$ because Span$\{1, x\}$+Span$\{1+x+x^2+x^3, 1+x+x^2-x^3\}$=$(a+c+d)+(b+c+d)x+(c+d)x^2+(c-d)x^3$ which represents any polynomial.

For $W\cap W_2=\{0\}$, again, I don't know how to show it.

Could someone fix my procedure?

Comment: I think that saying that $(a+c+d) + (b+c+d)x + (c+d)x^2 + (c-d)x^3$ represents any polynomial is a bit of a leap. The correct way to do it is by starting with any polynomial $\alpha + \beta x + \gamma x^2 + \delta x^3$ and finding the corresponding $a, b, c, d$

Answer (score 1):

$W\cap W_1=\{0\}$

To prove it, you need to find a non-null linear combination of $\{1, x\}$ and show you cannot get any non-null polynomial of $Span\{x^2, x^3\}$.

Indeed:

$a+bx$ can never be equal to $cx^2+dx^3$

$W\cap W_2=\{0\}$

To prove it, you need to find a non-null linear combination of $\{1, x\}$ and show you cannot get any non-null polynomial of $Span\{1+x+x^2+x^3, 1+x+x^2-x^3\}$.

Indeed:

$a+bx$ can never be equal to $c(1+x+x^2+x^3)+d(1+x+x^2-x^3)=(c+d)+(c+d)x+(c+d)x^2+(c-d)x^3$

Comment: You should probably take it one step further and explain your reasoning by comparing coefficients